# Memory allocation of same item

Tags: python

I'm having a QGraphicsPathItem and it's internal property has allocated to an memory address and I have stored the memory address to the list. When I'm tried altering the same item(Extension of the item), the new property of the item will allocate to the same memory address and then I'm appending that to the same list.
My problem is when I'm appending the altered item to the list, the existing item and the current item has the same memory allocation address so the current item changes the property of the existing item. I need to store these two items without affecting any property. Please help me regarding this.

Comment: Where's your code?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow, you can provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to help people understand what your problem is